Playing ringtone in background, in iOS react native app. I am using react-native-sound library
I am using react-native-sound library to load and play sound in iOS.
When i receive a remote notification, I want that ringtone to play.
It works fine when app is in foreground state but it never plays the ringtone when iOS app is in background and inactive state
I tried adding
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
 <string>audio</string>
 <string>fetch</string>
 <string>processing</string>
 <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>

and also added my app target like this in info.plist
<key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
 <array>
  <string>{BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}</string>
 </array>

I tried cleaning cache, rebuilding it many times but without luck.
I expected the ringtone to play smoothly as it worked in foreground state.

Welcome to Stack overflow. Your question would benefit from using tags that are relevant to your audience not the technologies you may be using. Tagging your question e.g. firebase-cloud-messaging exposes it to followers of that tag but it's unclear whether that audience has any insight into helping answer your question.

Are you sending a silent notification? What code do you have in your app to receive the notification and play the sound when your app is in the background?  Can you just use the custom sound option in the APNS payload?
